# How to pass arguments to a script through the SpiderMonkey command-line?

Tags: command-line-arguments, spidermonkey

I am using SpiderMonkey 1.8.5 on Debian.
I am starting a script through the command-line using

```
js -f <myScript>
```

I'd like to pass some arguments to my script, but I don't know how to do that. It's supposedto be possible since [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/SpiderMonkey/Shell_global_objects) tells you about a special object gathring all parameters provided to a script.

I tried the following:

```
js -f <myScript> <1stArg>
```

But SpiderMonkey consider both parameters as different scripts to execute and thus sends en error saying the '<1stArg>' file doesn't exist.

What is the correct way to do what I wish?

Comment: Which lines in the documentation you refers to talk about "gathering all parameters provided to a script"?

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

In script.js

```
#!/usr/bin/js
print(arguments);
```

Then from system shell:

```
$ chmod +x script.js
$ ./script.js
```